# I can't install ubuntu 17.04 or 16.04 on my system

Tags: nvidia, hdmi

I have the following system:

```
BIOS:   American Megatrends Inc. F6, 30/05/2014
Motherboard: Gigabyte Z97X-Gaming 7
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz, 4001 Mhz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970
RAM: Ballistix Tactical 16GB Kit (8GBx2) DDR3 1600 MT/s (PC3-12800) UDIMM 240-Pin - BLT2CP8G3D1608DT1TX0CEU
```

And when I try to install `ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64` or `ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64` into my system I get this screen:

[image]

I have connect my screen using HDMI to the graphics card. Sorry, but I don't have a DVI screen.

And I don't know if it is related to this but my system clock get delayed two hours.

I have installed successfully CentOS 7.0 on my system without any problem.

Is there any problem with my graphics card? What can I do?

I have also the same problem if I try it without installation. By the way, I am installing it from a CD.

If you need more details, please tell me.

Comment: @VansFannel -- you most likely need the nomodeset answer. from the link provided by Pilot6. Some systems don't fully enable the graphics card at boot.

Comment: @ravery Thanks for the explanation. I have installed changed the command line to nomodeset.